# Undefined while getting array element by index written in the variable in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It seems to me that I found some sort of bug. Basically I want to get components object by index (for the  tag). But I've experienced a strange issue. I've included necessary pieces of my code below:

**Working example:**

```
let steps = ['Handler', 'Categories', 'Finalize'];
export default {
    components: {
        Handler,
        Categories,
        Finalize
    },

    data() {
        return {
            step: 0,
            currentStep: steps[0] // When specifying index without a variable 
        }
    },

}
```

**Broken example:**

```
let steps = ['Handler', 'Categories', 'Finalize'];
export default {
    components: {
        Handler,
        Categories,
        Finalize
    },

    data() {
        return {
            step: 0,
            currentStep: steps[this.step] // When specifying index by a variable 
        }
    },
}
```

In working example I am getting component (as expected), but in broken I am getting `currentStep: undefined` in Vue DevTools. However, no errors in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what `this` binds to in your `data` definition? With a `console.log(this)`?

Comment: I've just dumped `this` to the console. What should I look for?

Comment: `this` should bind to `Vue` and not be `undefined`

Comment: `Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`

Comment: If you want to use `this.step` then create a variable in `data()`, then use it to return. As of now, there is no attribute named `step` in `data()`. Hence can't do `this.step`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to move the `currentStep` to a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Also, `steps` need to exist in `data` so they are reactive:

```
let steps = ['Handler', 'Categories', 'Finalize'];
export default {
    components: {
        Handler,
        Categories,
        Finalize
    },

    data() {
        return {
            step: 0,
            steps,
        }
    },
    computed: {
      currentStep() {
        return this.steps[this.step];
      }
    }
}
```

If possible, prefer to stick the `steps` directly in data:

```
data() {
    return {
        step: 0,
        steps: ['Handler', 'Categories', 'Finalize'];,
    }
},
```

(But that may not be possible if you're importing them from the outside. I don't know about your specific use case).

In general, in Vue, when something directly depends on the value of some component properties, computed properties are the way to go: they are performant and clear.

In your original code, should it have worked, `currentStep` would not react to a change in `step`. Using a computed property, instead, whenever the `step` updates, the `currentStep` will update accordingly.

Comment: 5 sec ago managed to fix it by itself exactly like you did ;D Well, thanks for the answer!